# What does the >> mean in the MOVE command?

Tags: batch-file

```
MOVE /Y "\\web\OApp\Uploads\Submitted\*.*" "\\app\OSubmit\Attachments" >> "\\web\OApp\Uploads\copyLog.txt"
```

I have done Moves in batch files before but I'm not familiar with the `>>` symbol

I'm thinking this moves everything from `\\web\OApp\Uploads\Submitted` into `\\app\OSumit\Attachments`
but after the `>>` I don't know what the `\\web\OApp\Uploads\copLog.txt` string does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just *redirects* the output of the move command (the status messages that it prints out) into a log file (instead of having them show up on the console).

`>` overwrites the destination file, while `>>` appends to it.